# Why would the Russian government use hackers and email leaks to try to interfere with the 2016 U.S. presidential election?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, presidential-election, russian-federation, espionage

Assuming the *[Joint Statement from the Department Of Homeland Security and Office of the Director of National Intelligence on Election Security](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2016/10/07/joint-statement-department-homeland-security-and-office-director-national)* is correct that:

> only Russia’s senior-most officials could have authorized these activities

Why would a Trump presidency be in Russia's interest?

Comment: Not sure there's any answer that can be given here that wouldn't be wild speculation.

Comment: There are at least three questions here, (1) reasons for Russian state cyber-terrorism and (2) reasons why Russians interfere a sovereign country's election process; (3) reasons for [Russian support for Trump](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12057/2984). You may need, however, expanding your question(s) to make it more specific and answerable.

Comment: daily reminder that you should take propaganda with a grain of salt.  The DNC reported that russians "hacked" into Podestas twitter account.  1) that isn't what hacking means. 2) his password was in wikileaks.  The DNC is lying so that people know about the leaks but their contents aren't reported.

Comment: This Q. could use an updated lead sentence that succinctly encapsulates whatever [the Mueller report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mueller_Report) has to support the opening premise, which clearly is no longer just a stray DHS hypothesis.

Answer (score 6):

There are multitude of reasons (and absent Putin's confidential documents being leaked, no way to be sure at this time). Three of the possibilities:

1. Russians - and especially Putin's cohort - have a deep and abiding hatred of Bill Clinton over his aggression against Serbia and him engineering what Russia sees as theft of Kosovo.

   This is not something most Americans appreciate, but to Russians, Serbs are basically blood brothers. Not just in a sense of "We will post angry comments on YouTube", but in a sense of "the last time a major power threatened Serbia, Russia brought its full military might as a state to bear. The year was 1914".

   It is not inconceivable that Hillary is seen by Russian powers as Bill Clinton's Presidency #3. They would go to great lengths to avoid that. I would dismiss the motive being pure revenge on Bill, as too hot-blooded and short-sighted for Russian power elites.

   ---
2. Plus, Clinton, aside from being seen as a likely Bill #3, would also be seen as Obama #3, as far as foreign policy (her being a happy cheerleader of it as his SecState).

   Russians aren't too happy with the **intent** (as opposed to execution) of Obama's foreign policy, which they see as antagonistic to them, and a continuation of since-1990 encroachment that successive US governments acted upon, with moving NATO closer to Russia's heartland and chipping away at Russia's geopolitical positions.

   ---
3. An opposite explanation is that, conversely, Russian power elites view Republican presidency as detrimental to their geopolitical interests (this is not quite about personalities of Clinton or Trump but more about the prevailing ideologies of "America is Great" vs "Kumbaya" that drive the two parties, to condense the ideas to bumper sticker levels.

   This is not as contradictory to #1/#2 above as it seems, since they see both R and D as anti-Russian, but Rs as far more determined and effective at it, due to absence of peacenicks and American-nonexceptionalism in the party.

   If that is the case, it's not inconceivable that they played a masterful psychological game, and deliberately created an obvious appearance of helping Trump, in the hopes that it would damage his candidacy *(granted, a cheaper way to achieve the same result would have been to give Trump a gift of a free microphone, but I digress)*.

## Again, we don't really know the actual reason and can only guess.

Comment: Correction: The last time a major power threatened Serbia was not in 1914 but in 1941 (Germany invasion of Yugoslavia, which included Serbia), and the SU did not go to war because of that. Also, I find strange that your answer forgets the many times Trump has expressed his admiration for Putin's Russia, Putin and his client Al-Assad; your answers usually are well informed.

Comment: And for the "Russian and Serbs are blood brothers", in reality it just amounts to the centuries long struggle of the Russian rulers to get to control the Straits so its fleet and commerce is not at the mercy of whoever controls the Bosphorus. They first supported Greece independence movement, then turned towards Bulgaria, then Serbia. The "support of our Orthodox brothers" was a good excuse to start new wars against the Ottoman Empire and gain influence further South, but apart for that is was just politics as usual.

Comment: Now we're getting into iocane powder territory.

Comment: @SJuan76 US, surely, has teared Yougoslavia and then Serbia apart for a different reason, not because Yougoslavia-Russian relationship, right? You say so, it must be right.

Comment: @SJuan76 - There is a big difference between admiring Putin as a leader (and he is an extremely effective and talented leader and head of state) and sharing Putin's goals. Hell, ***I*** admire Putin, and I have far more reasons than Trump to oppose him as a state actor. The moment Putin goes against what Trump wants, that admiration will be entirely academic. Trump in general admires winners, which fact he shares with 99% of human population, be they people who admire sexuall-assault-happy sports stars or those who admire equally-odious-as-persons entertainment stars (or look at BillC's fans).

Comment: @SJuan76 - I'm not talking about pragmatic decision making by Russian heads of state only. I'm talking about opinions of Russian populace, as well (and the leaders as part of said populace). They happen to completely coincide in the case of Serbia.

Comment: @SJuan76 - By the way, to further annul your opinion that Trump's admiration is somehow relevant here: apparently, Clinton was no less effusive in her praise: http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2016/10/12/clinton-bashes-trump-over-russia-praise-but-emails-show-praised-putin.html

Answer (score 2):

Trump is more isolationist and if USA stays away from the rest of the world that would give Russia more space to operate.

Answer (score -3):

Because Clinton promises a war against Syria and Russia whereas Trump promised a hand of friendship and ally with Assad to fight the terrorism in the Middle East. Trump sounds considerate and sane. Who do you think would Russians to prefer?

It is resonable, it is what Russian Media says, in including [Putin himself](https://youtu.be/YVdmwger13g?t=631). But, this is not acceptable reason, right? Russians must have a cunning plan. [You cannot](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12545), but Russians certainly have it and we must silence the outright reason. We must ascribe our reasons to Russians. This way, we can be more efficient to combat their cunning plan. It is always easier to demonize the enemy by not letting them speak and ascribing our dirty insinuations to em.

Comment: Here I was under the impression that the Russians hoped Trump would win because they may consider him the harbringer of American apocalypse, rather than viewing him as considerate and sane.

Comment: @JeffLambert It is ridiculous to hear that you are unaware that Trump is ostracized for reverance towards the Russa but you believe that Clinton is sane because you are not reported this [Paul Joseph Watson Hillary -Threatens War With Russia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4aIIpCDsLU)

Comment: I highly doubt that Trump actually feels any reverence for Russia whatsoever, and he, just like Putin, play their cards in a way that they see would benefit them the most (like pretty much all other politicians). This is why I offer you a different viewpoint, which I myself find much less _ridiculous_ than Putin (or anyone else for that matter) actually believing in his heart that Trump is 'considerate' in any way.

Comment: @JeffLambert Please be explicit. You say that you should equally treat both people, regardless what they say. One says that he will talk with you pragmatically, another says that you is a Devil on the Earth, and you will be exterminated when I become president? Please tell that this should not affect my attitudes.

Comment: Yes Trump says lots of things. The best things with the best words. But then he back tracks on himself and reality so much that I find it hard to believe that Putin would actually take him at his word. The smallest slight against him (as indicated by how Trump is now treating the current House Speaker) would bring the full fury of Trump's ego regardless of whatever pleasantries they may have shared. It is much more likely that Putin wants to see America fail or look bad and sees Trump as the best tool for the job. This is why I believe your answer has been downvoted.

Comment: You accuse Trump of telling too much good words. I asked you to be explicit. Just tell that when one person says that you are negotiable when another says that you is a Devil and Hitler alive and needs to be nuked, you say that you do not care about that. Regarding Putin beliving that Trump will self-destroy your lovely country, I can tell you do not think us to be so children/fools. Russians understand that US president does not play a lot. The country is run by elites. The president can only sigh a petition to start a war or not follow the public opinion, which is framed by yor owners.

Comment: @JeffLambert If stupid Bush did not ruin your country, then Trump won't be allowed that for sure. I also did not get how is it possible that a person who tells a lot and tells right things is demonstration crazy. It was told to you: Clinton will start the war with Russia. She told hereself. I live in Estonia, I see that Estonians (and all Baltic, Nordic states and the Europe from Ukraine to Romaina and Poland) are looking forward to that. You keep playing fool. Who is crazy?

Comment: I have noticed that the well-received answer silences the fact that Trump had admired the Putin. You find all reasons not listen to the real world, what Russian media says, for instance. This is how you know who uses chemical weapons, who is crazy tyrant, slaughering his population because he is crazy and where terrorists need support to remove that barbarous regime and [make one mistake after another](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12545/how-can-one-prove-that-us-has-an-imperialistic-plan). Is it [a real mistake or a plan?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12543/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46651/discussion-between-jeff-lambert-and-little-alien).